# Replacing Javascript file in Google Chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension

I would like to replace a javascript file in my Google Chrome cache such that when I reload a website it will run my modified script. I could do a whole setup with puppeteer instead but it would be just way easier if I could just replace the cached file. However, I cannot seem to locate my cache or any info on wether this is possible since the data might be encrypted or encoded. Alternatively is there an extension that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a JavaScript file in your Google Chrome cache by following these steps:

1. Open Chrome and press F12 to open the developer tools.
2. Go to the "Application" tab in the developer tools and select "Cache" from the left sidebar.
3. Find the JavaScript file you want to replace in the cache and select it.
4. Right-click on the selected file and choose "Delete" to remove it from the cache.
5. Refresh the website to reload it and run your modified script.
6. To run the modified script, you can use the "Sources" tab in the developer tools to open the file and paste in your changes.